# Redirect to another server site without changing domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two servers running Apache2, one with an associated domain name, let's say "www.home.com" and another one only known by its IP address, let's say 10.11.12.13.

On www.home.com I have three web sites, configured through aliases in apache.
I have http://www.home.com, http://www.home.com/school, http://www.home.com/work.
All these sites are on the server www.home.com.

On 10.11.12.13, I have only one site, accessible by http://10.11.12.13/wiki

**How can I configure apache to have http://www.home.com/wiki working but transparently (not changing URL) call http://10.11.12.13/wiki site ?**

In other words, the user shall only see www.home.com/wiki/xxxxx when he uses the wiki.

What I have done:

- On www.home.com : i have added a wiki folder with nothing in it, and an alias for www.home.com/wiki to work properly.

Then I have tried to use mod rewrite to replace 10.11.12.13 by www.home.com but that does not work, and I am not even sure to do it the right way.

For your information, mod rewrite is configured and works properly on both servers.

Someone could please help me on that ?
**Maybe mod rewrite is not the right solution ?**

Thanks !
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution : the mod_proxy along with  tags.

The conf that worked for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  [...]
  ServerName www.home.com
  <Location /wiki>
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass       "http://10.11.12.13/wiki"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://10.11.12.13/wiki"
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```